# Delay fb api call using setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to delay a fb api call. I am trying to schedule a facebook post using facebook api and i want to delay it a little bit. However, i notice that when i use setTimeout function across my fb api call, the post doesn't get scheduled at all (though the api call is called a little bit later..which means that setTimeout function is working fine but the post is not getting scheduled.)

Here is the code:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  FB.login(function() {         

    FB.api('/' + my_p_id, {
      fields: 'id, access_token'
    }, function (response) {
      var access_token = response.access_token;
      FB.api('/'+my_p_id+'/photos', 'post', {
        'message': '',
        'access_token': access_token,
        'url': imgArray[i],
        'scheduled_publish_time': Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 720,
        'published': false
      }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);

      });
    });
  }, {
    scope: 'email,publish_actions,manage_pages,publish_pages'
  });

}, 6000); //end setTimeout function
```

Comment: You’re not delaying the API call, you are delaying the call to `FB.login`. // _Why_ are you trying to “delay” anything here, what are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: Actually i want to post 2 photos.. and i want a delay between those 2 photos .. that is why i need to delay the call.

Comment: And even if i am delaying the call to fb.login .. shouldn't it still have worked?